# Function pointer with default behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

In my program I have a lot of pointers to functions provided by an external library. Some of them return value, and some of them not.

If external library did not provide function (pointer is NULL) and function should return value program should assume default value (which is known at compile time).

What I try to accomplish is to reduce amount of `if` statements and to wrap pointer in class with following use case:

```
enum E { e1, e2, e3 };
UserFunction<uint8_t(int, int), 0> callback1 { user_function_ptr }; // Calls and returns value of user_function_ptr
UserFunction<uint8_t(), 0> callback2 { nullptr }; // Returns 0
UserFunction<uint8_t(), 1> callback3 { nullptr }; // Returns 1
UserFunction<E(int), e1> callback4 { user_function_ptr2 }; // Returns enum value and takes one integer argument
UserFunction<void(int)> callback5 { user_function_ptr3 }; // No return value, one argument
UserFunction<void()> callback6 { nullptr }; // Should perform noop
```

What I got so far is working for functions that return value:

```
template <class Sign, int Def>
struct UserF;

template <class R, int Def, class... Args>
struct UserF<R(Args...), Def> {
    typedef R Signature(Args...);
    typedef typename std::add_pointer<Signature>::type SignaturePtr;

    static R Default(Args... args) {
        return (R) Def;
    }

    UserF() {
        functionToCall = Default;
    }

    UserF(SignaturePtr userFunction) {
        if (userFunction != nullptr) {
            functionToCall = userFunction;
        } else {
            functionToCall = Default;
        }
    }

    R operator() (Args... args) {
        return functionToCall(args...);
    }

private:
    SignaturePtr functionToCall;
};
```

The problem with code above is that it forces default value to be `int`. What I could do is change `UserF` template to something like this:

```
template <class R, R Def, class... Args>
struct UserF {
    // ...
};
// use case
UserF<E, e1, int> callback; // Returns E, takes int, default e1
```

But if it possible I would rather use

```
UserF<R(Args...), Default> callback; // preferred
UserF<Default, R(Args...)> callback; // if above is not possible
UserF<void(Args...)> callback; // if no return value
```

I would rather not use `std::function` since I know that I will be dealing only with pointers to functions, and not with pointers to member functions, functor objects, etc. Also boost is not allowed (C++11 is allowed).

To summarize, the question is: How to force type check on default return value.

Comment: Cannot `Default` be in constructor instead of template parameter ?

Comment: @jarod42 probably should be, as it takes gymnastics to make it work with double return type (etc)

Comment: @Jarod42 Default value could be passed in constructor, but I think syntax I proposed is cleaner. Moreover it would require to store default value in memory per function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class Sig>
struct return_type;
template<class Sig>
using return_type_t=typename return_type<Sig>::type;
template<class R,class...Args>
struct return_type<R(Args...)>{
  using type=R;
};

template <class Sign, return_type_t<Sign> Def>
struct UserF;
```

is most of it.  To handle `void` you'll want a flag trick:

```
struct void_flag{};
template<class T>
using flag_void=
  typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T,void>{},void_flag*,T>::type;

template <class Sign, flag_void<return_type_t<Sign>> Def=nullptr>
struct UserF;

template <class R, R Def, class... Args>
struct UserF<R(Args...), Def>{
  // body

template <class... Args>
struct UserF<void(Args...), 0>{
  // body
```

there will be problems with non-integral non-pointer `R`, as you cannot pass a `double` to a `template`.  One approach would be to upgrade `double` to `double const*` for `Def`, and have it auto-dereference:

```
template <class R, R const* Def, class... Args>
struct UserF<R(Args...), Def>{
  // body
```

and do something like `flag_void` to turn `T=double` into `T=double const*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can stomach a small macro, you could do this:

```
template <typename sig, typename T, T v >
struct UserF_;

template <class R, typename ... Args, typename T, T v >
struct UserF_< R(Args...), T, v > {
    // ...
};
#define UserF( F, Default ) UserF_< F, decltype( Default ), Default >

UserF(R(Args...), Default) callback;
```

You cannot have a generic template non-type parameter without first specifying its type as a template type parameter.